# Show and hide an iframe with condition

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a one page homepage with below structure. In the portfolio section i have embeded a paypal button. I am planing to use the auto return function of paypal where buyers are brought back to my page upon payment completion. And in the Contact section i have embeded an iframe which is a survey made with google docs. I want to show this only buyers who completed purchase. How can i do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mini</title>     
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Nav -->
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul class="container">
                <li><a href="#top"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#work"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    <!-- Home -->
        <div class="wrapper style1 first">
            <article class="container" id="top">
                    <div>
                    </div>                  
            </article>
        </div>

    <!-- Work -->
        <div class="wrapper style2">
            <article id="work">                 
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </article>
        </div>

    <!-- Portfolio -->
        <div class="wrapper style3">
            <article id="portfolio">                    
                <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                //Here is the paypal button
                </form>
            </article>
        </div>

    <!-- Contact -->
        <div class="wrapper style4">
            <article id="contact" class="container 75%">                    
                    <div class="row">
                        //below the survey made with google docs
                        <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/...</iframe>
                    </div>

            </article>
        </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try with [HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Answer (score -1):

you can check for referrer

*JavaScript solution*

```
<script>
    var referrer = document.referrer;
    if (referrer == 'paypal domain here') {
        document.getElementById("iframeidhere").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

And add same ID to that iframe, and also add `style="display:none";` to it

*PHP solution*

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'here you put PayPal domain') { ?>
    // Your iframe here
<?php } ?>
```

You can not rely on it 100%, someone can spoof this variable, but if it is not security problem for your Google form it is easy and fast solution.

Other solution would be to check and validate return URL from PayPal

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try it asap.

Comment: This isn't a good approach, as even thought the display is "none" still the iframe will be loading in the background and will slow down the page even when it's not required.